# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n} \sin(n) $

Tags: complex-analysis

Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n} \sin(n) $

I found this answer :

Clearly, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \leq 1$. Since the interval $[\pi/4, 3\pi/4]$
has length greater than $1$, $n (mod \ 2\pi) \in [\pi/4, 3\pi/4]$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ and hence $\sin n \geq 1/ \sqrt{2}$ for
infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$. Hence $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \geq 1$ also. So $R = 1$

I didn't get the second part saying  $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \geq 1$.
Please give some more ideas, Thank you!

Comment: $\lim_n (1/\sqrt2)^{1/n} = 1$.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm thinking OP is confused by the bit about the sequence $n \mod 2\pi$ falling in this interval infinitely often. Easy to convince oneself of, a bit tedious to write formally i suppose

Comment: Let $n_k$ denote the indices for which $\sin n_k\ge 2^{-1/2}.$  Then $1\ge \lim_k(\sin n_k)^{1/n_k}\ge \lim_k2^{-1/(2n_k)}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $|z|<1.$ Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\sin n={1\over 2i}\left [\sum_{n=0}^\infty (ze^i)^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (ze^{-i})^n\right ]\\ ={1\over 2i}\left [{1\over 1-ze^i}-{1\over 1-ze^{-i}}\right ]=:f(z)
$$
The function $f(z)$ has two poles in the unit circle, at $e^{ i}$ and  $e^{-i}.$ Therefore the radius of convergence of its MacLaurin series is equal $1.$